# Forgot root password for kali live persistent usb

Tags: kali-linux

Is there any way to reset the password? it is a persistent USB drive...

i was trying to set it up to have the same custom password every time i boot (not toor).

Comment: If I may, why is flagged as a duplicate. I think this is a valid question

Answer (score 1):

Boot any other Linux distribution.  Mount the USB, browse the mounted filesystem, and null out the `root` user's password in `/mnt/etc/passwd`.

Comment: tried that. not working.

Comment: Try `chroot  /mnt passwd root`